# CakePHP controller alias

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-2.2

I know there are a couple of other topics about this subject, but non of them seems to fit my needs.

**What I have**

- example.com/log/
- LogsController.php

I have `LogsController` instead of `LogController` (plural) because CakePHP wants you to have controllers in plural.

But as you might know/notice, `example.com/log/` will never use `LogsController` because of the missing 's' in the url.

Now, I want to have `/log/*` being redirected to `/logs/*`. Works perfectly fine with the following code:

```
Router::connect ('/log/*', array('controller'=>'logs'));
```

But, when I try to access `example.com/log/actions/foo/bar` it doesn't seem to work. So after some Googeling I found this:

```
Router::connect ('/log/:action/*', array('controller'=>'logs'));
```

Works great. But now when I'm trying to access example.com/log/ again, it says

> Error: LogController could not be found.

**Question**
So my question is, how do I set up an alias for my url so that `/log/` will use `LogsController` instead of trying to use `LogController`.

I have a few more Controllers where I'd like to change this, like `flight => FlightsController`, `profile => ProfilesController`.

---

Have a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12874722/). It is about the same subject, but slightly different. It might help you in some way.

Comment: Read this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9959152/define-a-singular-rule-in-the-bootstrap-for-inflector

Comment: It's easier to just tell cake that "flight" is both singular and plural.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Ok, with the help of some other people on IRC and stuff like that. I found out the following.

A combination of

```
Router::connect('/flight/:action/*', array('controller'=>'flights'));
Router::connect('/flight/*', array('controller'=>'flights'));
```

does the trick. I tried this before, but in a other order, like so:

```
Router::connect('/flight/*', array('controller'=>'flights'));
Router::connect('/flight/:action/*', array('controller'=>'flights'));
```

which doesn't work.

So the first 2 lines of code in this post solved it for me. Another guy told me that the solution of Arun Jain isn't a proper solution, because it changes the nameconventions in the core as well. Which will cause problems with the FormsHelper and classes like that. So I think I will prefer the code in this post since this is just an alias instead of a core changing piece of script. Thanks for the help anyway.

Answer (score 1):

To do this with routing the correct approach is as follows.

```
Router::connect('/flight', array('controller'=>'flights','action'=>'index'));
Router::connect('/flight/:action/*', array('controller'=>'flights'));
```

This tells the router that when an action is found in the URL to use it, but it no params are found then to default is to use the index action.

Answer (score 0):

I have a slightly different take on all of this.  The plural is more often the more accurate way to go with things but in occassions when the plural is just plain wrong, i add an exception into the Inflector class (/lib/Cake/Utility/Inflector).

In your example I would add `log` to this list of `uninflected` words.  This means that system wide cake will not append the 's'. You'll have your `LogController` your views would sit in the `Log` view folder etc...

**EDIT**

I've come across a much neater way to do this from within `app/config/bootstrap.php`

```
Inflector::rules(
    'plural',
    array(
         'uninflected' => array('log')
    )
);
```

This would add `log` to the uninflected list without having to alter the files within the Core to allow easier version updating.

Comment: But that meanse I would be editing files in the core. Which I don't want. Because I want to be able to update Cake with a click on a button. So perhaps I have to extend the class, but that would really be a pain. I guess there are some nice methods for that. I will research it when I have time :) Tnx for the thinking

Answer (score -1):

You can simply do it using following:

```
class LogsController extends AppController
{
public $name = 'Log';
..... YOUR REMAINING CODE ......
}
```

Your router connnect code will remain same. Kindly ask if it not worked for you.

Comment: I tried this, but it doesn't seem to work. I changed the $name in FlightsController to 'Flight', but when I try to access example.com/flight it says that the FlightController is missing.

Comment: No, the name variable is for backward compatibility with PHP4. It will have no impact on routing cause the controller is loaded "after" routing is performed.