# Cakephp Controller alias not working completely

Tags: php, cakephp

I have a new question related to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11925578/cakephp-controller-alias), but since the questions do not match at all, I am creating this new topic. But it is for good reference.

---

I changed my mind about the `logs` to `log` thing, `logs` is fine. But I am having another controller called `WikisController`, in this case I would really like to change the URL. I just hate it that the URL will be `example.com/wikis/subject.html`, I want it to be `example.com/wiki/subject.html`. It is much cleaner and the convention is now a 100% match with other sites where it is also called `wiki`, and not `wikis`. But, I want the controller to be called `WikisController`, because of the `CakePHP` convention.

Well, now comes the real problem. I was currently using the following routing in `Config/routes.php`:

```
Router::connect('/wiki/:action/*', array('controller' => 'wikis'));
Router::connect('/wiki/*', array('controller' => 'wikis'));
```

This is the piece of code used by the solution in the [other topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11925578/cakephp-controller-alias). But now I am running into a little bit of trouble. Well, it isn't really a big issue because everything works just fine. But I don't like the URL.

When I create a link as the following from `example.com/wiki/edit.html`:

```
echo $this->Html->link('Wiki overview', array(
    'controller' => 'wikis',
    'action' => 'index',
    'ext' => 'html'
));
```

It is creating a link to `example.com/wiki/index.html` totally fine and it works, but I don't want to show the `index.html`, I just don't. It is a word extra in the url and it is not necessary for the user to understand where he is.

I am creating the `link` with the `controller` and `action` key because of a little bug I was having earlier. When I didn't specify the `action`, it would create a link to `example.com/edit.html` which I don't want, obviously. So I have to add the `action => index` key to the array. I am not sure if this is a real bug, but it shouldn't matter. `Index = index` and nothing changes that. It is a good thing that I am sure my URL is pointing to the right page, so adding the `action` isn't an issue for me.

*Just for good notice:*

When I am creating a link on exactly the same way as I did above to `example.com/flights/index.html` from the page `example.com/flights/add.html` it would delete the `/index` part from the url and simply create a url to `example.com/flights.html` which is much cleaner.

So it has to do something with the routing, but I can't figure out what.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood you correctly, then you'll need a route that connects `/wiki` to the controllers `index` action:

```
Router::connect('/wiki', array('controller' => 'wikis', 'action' => 'index'));
Router::connect('/wiki/:action/*', array('controller' => 'wikis'));
...
```

Comment: This solution seems to work quite well. I have to test it a bit more to be 100% sure though. If it is the fix I will mark this post as the answer. Thanks :) I removed the second line of my current routing and that doesn't give any warnings or errors. So changing the second line to the first line of yours and changing the order did the trick.

Comment: Ok I tested it a bit and it seems to work fine. If I run in any problems after all I will let you guys know. And I will post a link to this question in the earlier question.