# CakePHP Plugin - how to setup Apache Rewrite for vanity URL

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, cakephp

Been trying to figure this out for a few days now with no joy. Here's my setup: I have a CakePHP install in

```
/home/user/tools/cakephp
```

and a plugin at

```
/home/user/tools/cakephp/app/Plugin/MyPlugin
```

The Apache server setup is such that I've set the DocRoot to /home/user/tools, so browsing to

```
http://myserver.com/cakephp/my_plugin
```

works fine, but now my client wants to set it up so that

```
http://myserver.com/product-name
```

serves up the CakePHP plugin, and all subsequent routes are honoured. Has anyone had any experience setting something like this up? Has to be Apache, unfortunately, and can be done with a mixture of config/.htaccess (clients constraints).

Thanks
Stephen

Comment: You can set this up in the routes.php file - have a look at the routing page in the manual: http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/development/routing.html#plugin-routing

Comment: No, I cant. The "product-name" part of the URL has nothing to do with Cake, needs to be configured by Apache.

Comment: This seems trivial regarding on your question: `RewriteRule ^product-name$ /cakephp/my_plugin [L]`

Comment: So the alias must be defined on apache level, but can PHP be used to assist handling the values defined via apache config/.htaccess?

Comment: Ps. Are the other parts of your app working? For instance: the default `/pages/display/home` url? Since I have a feeling your DocumentRoot isn't set correctly for [production](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/installation.html#production) ..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are saying you have to do this via the Apache config or a .htaccess file, why? A plugin can have either his own Config/routes.php or you could configure the routing in your app wide app/Config/routes.php file. We are doing the same for a plugin we are using in our application.

What we did:

In the app wide routes file (app/Config/routes.php) we set a variable we use as our base url for accessing the plugin. We set it in a variable so we can easily switch when we get collisions with other controllers or plugins, so we want to keep that flexibility by doing the following:

```
# set the webroot for the plugin, for ajax calls and the sake of usability
$MyPluginBase = '/product-name';
# And we have this set just in case we need it somewhere in our application
Configure::write('MyPlugin.base', $MyPluginBase);
```

Then we configure our custom routes:

```
Router::connect($MyPluginBase . '/:name', array(
    'plugin'     => 'my_plugin',
    'controller' => 'my_plugin_products',
    'action'     => 'products'
));
Router::connect($MyPluginBase . '/some/other/url/*', array(
    'plugin'     => 'my_plugin',
    'controller' => 'my_plugin_some_controller',
    'action'     => 'whatever'
));
```

Now we can access the pugin via the 'product-name' url.

But, when you simply need a controller/action wide solution for this, you could accomplish this by using the following two routes:

```
Router::connect($MyPluginBase . '/:controller/:action/*', array(
    'plugin'     => 'my_plugin'
));
Router::connect($MyPluginBase . '/*', array(
    'plugin'     => 'my_plugin',
    'controller' => 'my_plugin_main_controller'
));
```

Please note that the order of Router::connect methods [matters](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11936402/1110760)!

---

ps. After reading the question again, I saw you have set your DocumentRoot wrong for production. Consult the following page in the cookbook for clarification: http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/installation.html#production

Comment: This looks promising, let me try it and I'll get back to you.

Comment: I found a work around but this answer was probably the most helpful, awarding the bounty.

Comment: @stephenmc Thank you very much :) Will you be so kind to update your question with your workaround? Just so that we and others with the same problem know your solution.

Answer (score 0):

Adding the following line to the htaccess file should work

```
RedirectMatch 301 cake/my_plugin(.*) /product-name$1
```

The above would resolve:

`http://myserver.com/cakephp/my_plugin` to `http://myserver.com/product-name`

`http://myserver.com/cakephp/my_plugin/somelink` to `http://myserver.com/product-name/somelink`

Answer (score 0):

When you say "all subsequent routes are honoured", I assume you mean that http://myserver.com/product-name/foo/bar will work the same as http://myserver.com/cakephp/my_plugin/foo/bar.

If that is the case, and you have `mod_alias`installed, all you need to do is provide an `Alias` directive in `httpd.conf`:

```
Alias /product-name /cakephp/my_plugin
```

This should be completely transparent to CakePHP; it will be unaware that this mapping is happening.

If you want to prevent direct requests to http://myserver.com/cakephp/..., you could also add an external redirect:

```
Redirect 301 /cakephp/my_plugin /product-name
```

(from http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_alias.html#alias)